# What is a viable approach for loading a large quantity of data originating in csv files?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

**Background**

Ultimately I'm trying to load a large quantity of data into GBQ. Records exist for the majority of seconds across many dates.

I want to have a table for each day's data so I may query the set using the syntax:
    _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170403' AND '20170408'...

Some of the columns will be nested and sets of columns currently originate from a high number of csv files each between 30-150mb in size.

**Approach**

My approach to processing the files is to:

**1) Create tables with correct schema**

**2) Fill each table with a record for each second in preparation for cycling through data and running UPDATE queries**

**3) Cycle through csv files and load data**

All this is intended to be driven by the GBQ client library for python.

Step (2) may seem odd, but I think it's needed in order to simplify the loading as I will be able to guarantee that UPDATE DML will work in all cases.

I do realise that (3) has little chance of working given the issues with (2), but I have run a similar operation at a slightly smaller scale leading me to believe that my approach might not be entirely hopeless at this larger scale.

I'm also left wondering whether this is the most appropriate method to load data of this nature, but some of the options presented in GBQ documentation seem like they could be overkill for a one-time load of data i.e I would not want to learn apache beam unless I know I have to given that my chief concern is analysing the dataset. But I'm not beyond learning something like apache beam if I know it's the only way of completing such a load as it could come in handy in future.

**Problem that I've run into**

In order to run (2) I have three nested for loops cycling through each hour, minute second and constructing a long string to go into the INSERT query:

```
(TIMESTAMP '{timestamp}', TIMESTAMP '2017-04-03 00:00:00', ... + ~86k times for each day)
```

GBQ doesn't allow you to run such a long query there is a limit, from memory it's 250k characters (could be wrong). For that reason the length of query is tested at each iteration and if it exceeds a number slightly lower than 250k characters then the insert query is performed.

Although this worked for a similar type of operation involving more columns when I run this this time the process terminates when GQB returns:

```
"google.cloud.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Resources exceeded during query execution: Not enough resources for query planning - too many subqueries or query is too complex.."
```

When I reduce the size of the strings and run smaller queries this error is returned less frequently, but does not disappear all together. Unfortunately at this reduced size of query the script would take too long to complete to serve as a feasible option for step (2). It takes >600 seconds and the entire data set would take in excess of 20 days to run.

I had thought that changing the query mode to 'BATCH' may overcome this, but it's been pointed out to me that this won't help, I'm not yet clear why, but happy to take someone's word for it. Hence I've detailed the problem further as it seems likely that my approach may be wrong.

This is what I see as the relevant code block:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud.bigquery import Client
... ...
bqc = Client()
dataset = bqc.dataset('test_dataset')
job = bqc.run_async_query(str(uuid.uuid4()), sql)
job.use_legacy_sql = False
job.begin()
```

What would be the best approach to loading this dataset? Is there a way of getting my current approach to work?

**Query**

```
INSERT INTO `project.test_dataset.table_20170403` (timestamp) VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2017-04-03 00:00:00'), ...   for ~7000 distinct values
```

**Update**

It seems as if the GBQ client library has had a not insignificant upgrade since I last downloaded it Client.run_asyn_query() appears to have been replaced with Client.query(). I'll experiment with the new code and report back.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'batch' query. How are you inserting data to BQ? is it live stream? Are you creating several insert jobs or is it just one job?

Comment: Hi @WillianFuks - it's referenced here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/running-queries#bigquery-query-python It's not a live stream I'm running a python script as a one time thing, but the script has to run multiple jobs as an error gets thrown when the length of the query string passes a limit, I think 250k limit, from memory.

Comment: Using batch queries will not help. Maybe you can give a sketch of the query that is triggering the error.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard - I'll do so. A quick point to note though, I had ruled out streaming the data in as its seems that this prevents DML on the table, you get a message about there being a streaming buffer. But if there's a way to stop the streaming buffer enabling further DML then this may prove to be the best option. Is there any such way of turning off the buffer after the data has been loaded?

Comment: @ElliottBrossard - I've re-framed the problem to make it more likely they you'll be able to spot any muddled thinking going on.

Comment: @Willian Fuks also giving you a heads up in case you're able to help. Cheers!

Comment: It might be worth noting that there are pretty low limits on the number of DML operations that can be performed, as described here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language so it might be better to build up the rows in python and then insert into BQ

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @DavidHodgson - this is what I'm doing though. The query only gets processed when it's length of characters approaches the threshold of what GBQ will allow.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard - even with the upgrade to the library I still get the same error referencing not enough resources for query planning

Comment: I didn't say that the client was the problem. I asked about the query since that is the issue.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard Sorry, my bad. I've added details of the query now.

Comment: It really sounds like you should use the streaming API instead of trying to make DML work with this many timestamp literals.

Comment: I'd agree with Elliott, BigQuery doesn't really support performing lots of INSERT and UPDATE operations. The way to manipulate data is via SELECT queries and writing the results to new tables. Could you upload all the source csv files into BQ and then query these tables to produce the same results?

Comment: Thanks both that's good to know. I'll work on how to do this with streaming inserts.